# Build node middleware - how to chain extern api call

Tags: node.js, api, middleware, nest

We have actually an API with some microservices.
But the API is not well designed for the front, not easy to use and understand.
I have to create a node **middleware** to simplify the actual use of the API.

*Ex :* to create a "house", the front need to make a first api call to get a free field, and a second api call to create the house. I need to build a middleware that **will do the logic to find the field and create the house**. So the front will make only one api call to the middleware (and the middleware will make 2 api call to the actual API).

But i don't know which node framework to use. I've find some ressources with nestjs. Also i'm wondering what would be the best structure to chain those api calls (as in the example).

Comment: You must also consider _transactional integrity_: If the first API call ("get free field") succeeds, but the second ("create house") fails, what will be the response of your middleware call? Or will you then try to undo the first call again ("get rid of field")?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen true. But for the moment i will do a simple error handling, if i get an error on the first api call, i will just send the same error (same logic if i have an error on the 2nd api call). 
Current need is urgent for front end development, a better error handling will be handled later.

Comment: Your middleware can make API requests with [`https.request`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/https.html#httpsrequestoptions-callback), or you can use a client library like [`axios`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios).

Comment: @HeikoTheißen thanks. I will figure out which one is the best to use for my need.